# Dropping columns in Table Container using Inputs

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, containers, dt

I'm using **Data Table** library in **Shiny** to create a *Table Container*.
I want to drop columns using **checkboxGroupInput or any input** but currently its not working.
Can someone please guide me? I shall be extremely grateful.

Same question is posted on R studio community as well, you can cross check answers:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-dropping-columns-in-table-container-using-inputs/17713/2

Regards

**My Codes:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui =basicPage(
tags$head(
tags$style(type = "text/css",
           HTML("th { text-align: center; }"))),

selectInput(inputId = "Species", 
          label = "Species:",
          choices = c("All",
                      unique(as.character(iris$Species)))),

checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns", label = "Select Variable:",
                        choices =c("All",names(iris)),selected = "All"),

h2('Iris Table'),
DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'))

server = function(input, output) {
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

  # a custom table container
  sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
    class = 'display',
    thead(
      tr(
        th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
        th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
        th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
      ),
      tr(
        lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th))) ))

  DT::datatable(filter = "top", container = sketch, rownames = FALSE, 
extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons =  c('copy', 
'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')),
                      {   
                   data<-iris[,c(5,1:4)]

                   if(input$Species != 'All'){
                     data<-data[data$Species == input$Species,]
                   }

                   if(input$Species[1]=="setosa"){
                     data<-data[data$species==input$species,]
                   }

                   if(input$columns=='All'){
                     data
                   }
                   else{
                     data[,c(input$columns),drop=FALSE]
                   }

                   data

                 })})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The `checkboxGroupInput` has different names for the columns than the actual column names, therefore when you are trying to sort by the input$columns no cols were selected throwing an error. Also you need to use the condition, ` `if(input$Species[1] ...){` to ensure you are checking for only the first element in a logical. You can sort data in the way you have shown but I am not sure how to make the  data table accept dropping columns.

Comment: My best idea would be to use the `sketch` function with reactive variables inside an observer in order to create the container based on the parameters.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks a lot for the suggestions, it's very kind of you. I have updated the checkboxGroupInput accordingly. For the rest of part i'm unable to figure out due to my limited knowledge. If possible could you please update the remaining code? That would be a great favor. Many thanks